# How replace strings after specific character?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

i'm trying to delete all strings after **||** in the following list:

`mylist=['   #  - || CAICEDO','LoL','lora',' moco','Sar || var']`

For that, i'm using:

```
def limp_2(n):
         return re.sub(r'^(\w+)-([\||\.])(.+)','',n)

clean_2=list(filter(limp_2,clean_1))
print(clean_2)
```

The idea is to get:

`mylist=['   #  - ','LoL','lora',' moco','Sar']`

Instead, I just have the same list. That is just an example, I want to apply that to a large list.

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Why is that you don't want to alter first element, but everything after `||` in some element of the list are removed ?

Comment: Just use `return n.split("||")[0].strip()` if you want to do what you asked - see https://rextester.com/ZYOHO99856

Comment: I would like to understand what have you make, what meands `[0].strip` and how is related with _.split_. I haven't found the part in `[]` as a parameter for _.split_. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a regex for that. You could simply use something like:

```
mylist = ['   #  - || CAICEDO', 'LoL', 'lora', ' moco', 'Sar || var']

clean_2 = [mylist[0]] + [s.split('||', 1)[0].rstrip() for s in mylist[1:]]

print(clean_2)
```

Result:

```
['   #  - || CAICEDO', 'LoL', 'lora', ' moco', 'Sar']
```